# How to Debug MIPS Interactively

Tags: gdb, mips

I'm taking a course on Computer Organization and Assembly.

In class, we're learning MIPS. This is for the purpose of introducing basic concepts, like pipelining. We're writing a handful of simple MIPS programs for class.

I'm used to gdb for debugging and learning, and the debugger we use in class is SPIM. SPIM sucks. It allows me to step through a program, but it doesn't allow me to interactively execute MIPS instructions at an arbitrary point of execution. I am immediately tired of having to exit SPIM, edit the source, and run SPIM again, navigating to the desired point of execution, only to see I have to do it again because I made yet another mistake.

Or perhaps I am mistaken and SPIM does allow this. My instructor said that this feature is not supported, so I'm going off what he said. I googled around a bit and didn't find a workaround.

I have tried googling for interactive MIPS debuggers like gdb but I haven't found any. I'm aware that gdb can debug MIPS programs, but I don't have a MIPS machine to run MIPS programs on.

I run Ubuntu in VMware. How can I interactively debug MIPS programs, using gdb or otherwise?

**Edit**: found some reference material on [Mips.com](https://www.mips.com/develop/tools/compilers/linux-toolchain/) on their recommended Linux Toolchain.

Comment: MARS is a bit more interactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `qemu` as an emulator, `gdb` as a debugger and `gcc` as a compiler. It's universal tool-set to investigate different architectures.

For Ubuntu you can install dependencies with followed command (probably, list is not full for your system - it's up to you there):

```
sudo apt install gdb-multiarch qemu qemu-user gcc-multilib gcc-multilib-mips64-linux-gnuabi64
```

Now you can use `gcc` as a compiler.

```
$ cat code.c 
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
$ mips64-linux-gnuabi64-gcc code.c -static -g3
```

And start emulation in `qemu` with debug session:

```
$ qemu-mips64 -g 1234 ./a.out
```

In `gdb-multiarch` use the following routine:

```
symbol-file a.out
set arch mips:isa64
target remote :1234
b main
c
```

And here is your goal:

```
(gdb) x/5i main
   0x120003850 <main>:  daddiu  sp,sp,-32
   0x120003854 <main+4>:    sd  ra,24(sp)
   0x120003858 <main+8>:    sd  s8,16(sp)
   0x12000385c <main+12>:   sd  gp,8(sp)
   0x120003860 <main+16>:   move    s8,sp
```

I believe, you can adapt it for your tasks. And `MIPS` arch is so various, as you can see in `gdb` `set arch` command.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain more why the -static option is needed? I have a guess, but I'd like to have it explained, if you don't mind.

Comment: @okovko, usually gcc don't process linkage stage (static or dynamic) without special flags. And then you execute your obj file, system used ld as interpretator for it. Usually, it's hidden from user. But it's not applicable for the emulator, which system is simpler. You need to pass there an elf (not obj). Also you need to pass there libs (multilib). The simples way is the static linkage. But you can manage it in your preferred way.

Comment: Also you can check your file with the `file` in linux. If it has a special signatures, it will tell you file format.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to help me again, I have a new and related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912129/how-to-disable-all-compilation-arguments-for-gdb-compile-code-command), when trying to use the `compile code` command in gdb.