# How to disable all compilation arguments for gdb compile code command?

Tags: c, gdb

Following this [process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59906042/how-to-debug-mips-interactively) 
from an earlier question (see answer).

gdb is a huge improvement over spim, but I'd like to use the compile code feature of gdb, to inject arbitrary mips instructions at the point of execution.

I have read [Compiling and injecting code in gdb](https://doc.ecoscentric.com/gnutools/doc/gdb/Compiling-and-Injecting-Code.html). When I run  run `compile code <anything>`, I get the error "compilation failed, unrecognized argument `-m32`". Then when I run `set debug compile` in gdb, and I try `compile code <anything>` again, I see that the argument `-m32` is passed to `mips-linux-gnu-gcc`.

I tried overriding the compilation arguments using `set compile-args -march=mips32r3`, which adds the compilation argument, but `-m32` is still passed and still gives me an error.

How do I prevent `-m32` from being passed? Is there a clean workaround (short of making a dummy script that strips `-m32` before compiling?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this script, `special-gcc`. Make it executable, `chmod 777 special-gcc`. The script uses `exec` to have the process replaced with the `gcc` invocation, as opposed to spawning a child process. Arguments are `$@`, stored in array, filtered in loop, then passed to the `gcc` invocation.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a args=()

#!/bin/bash
echo -- "----------------" >> ~/gcc-wrapper-log  
for arg in "$@"                               
do                                      
        if ! [[ "$arg" == '-m32' ]]; then                                
                echo -- "$arg" >> ~/gcc-wrapper-log                                                   
                args+=("$arg")                                                                                          
        fi                                                                                            
done                                                                                                  
exec mips-linux-gnu-gcc -static "${args[@]}"
```

Inside `gdb`, run the command `set compile-gcc /path/to/special-gcc`. Attempt some command `compile code <anything>`. Then in `gcc-wrapper-log` you can see all the arguments to the compilation, can selectively disable them in the script.

For me, the compilation succeeded, but because I am using the `mips-linux-gnu-gcc` cross compiler binary, `gdb` seems not to link the resulting `.o` file correctly. See [the docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GCCCompileAndExecute) for details on the internals of the `compile code` feature. Somewhere in the steps "Relocating the object file" is where the process failed for me for `mips-linux-gnu-gcc`.

However, this is still a clean and easy way to precisely control the compilation arguments used by `gdb compile code`.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I prevent -m32 from being passed?

It looks like this is the case where GDB developers thought that "GDB knows better", and didn't provide any way to override this.

Specifically, the `-m32` comes from `default_gcc_target_options()`, which unconditionally adds `-m%d` with `gdb_arch_ptr_bit()` as the argument.

Short of building your own GDB or providing a GCC wrapper that strips `-m32`, I don't see any way to get rid of this argument.

Comment: Fortunately making the wrapper isn't hard (if you know bash, or in my case, ask someone who knows bash), and unfortunately although the compilation succeeds, it appears the `compile code` feature is not made to work with the `mips-linux-gnu-gcc` cross compiler.