# Is LLDB compatible with gdbserver (for debugging cross compiled code?)

Tags: mips, lldb

I'm a CS student that just learned basic `mips` for class (Patterson & Hennessy + `spim`), and I'm attempting to find a `mips` debugging solution that allows arbitrary instruction execution during the debugging process.

**Attempt with gdb (so you know why not to suggest this)**

The recommended `mips` cross compilation tool chain is `qemu` and `gdb`, see [mips.com docs](https://www.mips.com/develop/tools/compilers/linux-toolchain/) and related [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59906042/how-to-debug-mips-interactively).

`gdb`'s `compile code` command does not support `mips-linux-gnu-gcc` as far as I can tell, see [gdb docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GCCCompileAndExecute) ("Relocating the object file") and related [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912129/how-to-disable-all-compilation-arguments-for-gdb-compile-code-command). I get errors for `malloc`, `mmap`, and invalid memory errors (something appears to be going wrong with the ad-hoc linking `gdb` performs) when attempting to use `compile code` with `mips-linux-gnu-gcc`, even after filtering the hard coded compilation arguments that `mips-linux-gnu-gcc` doesn't recognize.

**Actual question**

`lldb` has a similar command called `expression`, see [lldb docs](https://lldb.llvm.org/resources/architecture.html#expression), and I'm interested in using `lldb` in conjunction with `qemu`. The `expression` command also relies on `clang` as opposed to `gcc`, but [cross compilation in clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html) is relatively simple (`clang -target mips-linux-gnu` "just works"). The only issue is that `qemu-mips -g` launches `gdbserver`, and I can find no option for launching `lldb-server`.

I have read [lldb docs](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/remote.html) on remote debugging, and there is an option to select `remote-gdb-server` as the `platform`. I can't find much in the way of documentation for `remote-gdb-server`, but the name seems to imply that `lldb` can be compatible with `gdbserver`.

Here is my attempt to make this work:

```
qemu-mips -g 1234 test

lldb test
(lldb) platform select remote-gdb-server
  Platform: remote-gdb-server
  Connected: no
(lldb) platform connect connect://localhost:1234
  Platform: remote-gdb-server
  Hostname: (null)
  Connected: yes
(lldb) b main
  Breakpoint 1: where = test`main + 16 at test.c:4, address = 0x00400530
(lldb) c
  error: invalid process
```

Is there a way to either

1. use `lldb` with `gdbserver`, or to
2. launch `lldb-server` from `qemu-mips` as opposed to `gdbserver`

so that I can execute instructions while debugging `mips` code?

Note: I understand that I could instead use `qemu` system emulation to be able to just run `lldb-server` on the remote. I have tried to virtualize `debian mips`, using [this guide](https://markuta.com/how-to-build-a-mips-qemu-image-on-debian/), but the netinstaller won't detect my network card. Based on numerous SO Q/A and online forums, it looks like solving this problem is hard. So for now I am trying to avoid whole system emulation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YES

Use LLDB with QEMU

LLDB supports GDB server that QEMU uses, so you can do the same thing with the previous section, but with some command modification as LLDB has some commands that are different than GDB
You can run QEMU to listen for a "GDB connection" before it starts executing any code to debug it.

```
qemu -s -S <harddrive.img>
```

...will setup QEMU to listen on port 1234 and wait for a GDB connection to it. Then, from a remote or local shell:

```
lldb kernel.elf
(lldb) target create "kernel.elf"
Current executable set to '/home/user/osdev/kernel.elf' (x86_64).
(lldb) gdb-remote localhost:1234
Process 1 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGTRAP
    frame #0: 0x000000000000fff0
->  0xfff0: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0xfff2: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0xfff4: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0xfff6: addb   %al, (%rax)
```

(Replace localhost with remote IP / URL if necessary.) Then start execution:

```
(lldb) c
Process 1 resuming
```

To set a breakpoint:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set --name kmain
Breakpoint 1: where = kernel.elf`kmain, address = 0xffffffff802025d0
```

for your situation:

1. qemu-mips -s -S test;
2. lldb test
3. gdb-remote localhost:1234

here is my,you can reference:

```
#############################################   gdb    #############################################
QEMU_GDB_OPT := -S -gdb tcp::10001,ipv4
# 调试配置：-S -gdb tcp::10001,ipv4
qemudbg:
ifeq ($(BOOT_MODE),$(BOOT_LEGACY_MODE))
    $(QEMU) $(QEMU_GDB_OPT) $(QEMU_ARGUMENT)
else
ifeq ($(BOOT_MODE),$(BOOT_GRUB2_MODE))
ifeq ($(EFI_BOOT_MODE),n)
    $(QEMU) $(QEMU_GDB_OPT) $(QEMU_ARGUMENT) -cdrom $(KERNSRC)/$(OS_NAME).iso
else
    $(QEMU) $(QEMU_GDB_OPT) $(QEMU_ARGUMENT) -bios $(BIOS_FW_DIR)/IA32_OVMF.fd -cdrom $(KERNSRC)/$(OS_NAME).iso
endif
endif
endif

# 连接gdb server: target remote localhost:10001
gdb:
    $(GDB) $(KERNEL_ELF)


#############################################   lldb    #############################################

QEMU_LLDB_OPT := -s -S
LLDB := lldb

qemulldb:
ifeq ($(BOOT_MODE),$(BOOT_LEGACY_MODE))
    $(QEMU) $(QEMU_LLDB_OPT) $(QEMU_ARGUMENT)
else
ifeq ($(BOOT_MODE),$(BOOT_GRUB2_MODE))
ifeq ($(EFI_BOOT_MODE),n)
    $(QEMU) $(QEMU_LLDB_OPT) $(QEMU_ARGUMENT) -cdrom $(KERNSRC)/$(OS_NAME).iso
else
    $(QEMU) $(QEMU_LLDB_OPT) $(QEMU_ARGUMENT) -bios $(BIOS_FW_DIR)/IA32_OVMF.fd -cdrom $(KERNSRC)/$(OS_NAME).iso
endif
endif
endif


lldb:
    $(LLDB) $(KERNEL_ELF)
```